# Conditional updating row and using new row value as input for next row SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE "finishes" (
    "season"    INTEGER,
    "race"  TEXT,
    "driver"    TEXT,
    "team"  TEXT,
    "finish_position"   INTEGER,
    "gap_leader"    TEXT,
    "gap_ahead" TEXT,
    "number_of_laps"    INTEGER
);
```

Wit the following sample data

```
season  race    driver  team    finish  gap_leader  gap_1pos_ahead  number_of_laps
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    kimi raikkonen  ferrari 1   0   0   56
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    max verstappen  red bull racing 2   1.281   1.281   56
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    lewis hamilton  mercedes    3   2.342   1.061   56
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    sebastian vettel    ferrari 4   18.222  15.88   56
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    valtteri bottas mercedes    5   24.744  6.522   56
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    nico hulkenberg renault 6   87.21   62.466  56
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    carlos sainz    renault 7   94.994  7.784   56
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    esteban ocon    racing point    8   99.288  4.294   56
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    kevin magnussen haas f1 team    9   100.657 1.369   56
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    sergio perez    racing point    10  101.08  0.423   56
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    brendon hartley toro rosso  11  1L  32.942  55
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    marcus ericsson sauber  12  1L  1.289   55
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    stoffel vandoorne   mclaren 13  1L  1.383   55
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    pierre gasly    toro rosso  14  1L  23.154  55
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    sergey sirotkin williams    15  1L  12.318  55
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    lance stroll    williams    16  2L  56.257  54
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    charles leclerc sauber  17  25L 23L 31
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    daniel ricciardo    red bull racing 18  48L 23L 8
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    romain grosjean haas f1 team    19  54L 6L  2
2018    pirelli united states grand prix    fernando alonso mclaren 20  55L 1L  1
```

I want to update the `gap_leader` column values when they can be further specified.
The table shows that `brendon hartley` is `1L` behind the leader. However, this can  rewritten as

> 134.022 = 101.08 + 32.942 (gap_leader of sergio perez + gap_1pos of brendon hartley)

Only when we reach `charles leclerc` there is no further specification possible.
How do I write a loop that checks whether there is no "L" present in `gap_1pos_ahead` and update accordingly row-by-row.

I tried

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN gap_ahead NOT LIKE '%L' THEN 
    gap_ahead + LAG(gap_leader) OVER w ELSE
    gap_ahead END AS gap_leader_ahead
FROM finishes
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY season, race ORDER BY finish_position);
```

However, this only gives a good result for `brendon hartley` and the faster drivers. Afterwards this yields incorrect values.

Please advice